# Stimulsoft in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, compiler-errors, stimulsoft

I have problem with using stimulsoft in ASP.NET Core.

When I run my code, I get this error:

[image: Error Massege]

This is the code I use - in the controller:

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/747Ea.png)

And there is my view:

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HxBe.png)

and my Sheet is this:

[Stimulsoft Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWe3b.png)

Please help me

Comment: Please avoid showing code or error messages as images. Prefer posting it as code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes and the result you shared are right.

Make sure you call "printpage" action Not "print".
So the correct link to this report must be:
https://[controller-name]/printpage/id